# Finding the nearest number in a set in python

Tags: python, lambda, set

I'm almost there but if the number is the same distance as another number it's supposed to pick the smallest. How would I check for that?

```
def nearest_value(values: set, one: int) -> int:
    return min(values, key=lambda x: abs(x - one))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Example:")
    print(nearest_value({4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 17}, 9))
    print(nearest_value([0,-2],-1))
```

Comment: So if the number is `9`... and the options are `8` and `10` - you want `8` and not `10`?

Comment: Exactly, in the bottom print I want it to return -2 instead of 0.

Comment: Please show the expected value printed after each call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Change your key to also include the original value, eg:

```
def nearest_value(values: set, one: int) -> int:
    return min(values, key=lambda x: (abs(x - one), x))
```

Comment: I get TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. I'm a newbie with coding and I'm doing these coding missions.

Comment: @gogosimba sorry - didn't need that `[0]` at the end... use the above

Comment: Rather than using tuple as the key, create a list of such tuples, find the minimum according to the first element, then return the second element of the result.

Comment: @chepner that seems a little unnecessary vs using a tuple as key?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
def nearest_value(values: set, one: int) -> int:
    values = list(values)
    list_ = [i-one for i in values]
    return values[list_.index(min(list_))]


nearest_value({0, -2}, -1)
```

Output:

```
-2
```